# JQuery Select DIV by its For Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div for="data[staff][weight][]" class="has-error">Please enter a value for allowance breakdown</div>
```

I am trying to use jquery to select the closest data[staff][weight][] and remove it. I can't select by class because there are a few more div with the same class which is has-error (jquery validation)

```
($this).closest('data[staff][weight][]').remove();
```

Is there a way I can select the div by its "for" attribute.

**Thanks!**

Comment: [jQuery Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do this way

```
($this).closest('[for="data[staff][weight][]"]').remove();
```

**See Syntax**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Say something like bellow

```
($this).closest('[for="data[staff][weight][]"]').remove();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vz4166wf/)

**Note:-** Click on button to remove div in demo.

**References**

[Jquery Attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)